# How to create custom login and registration page in magento?

Tags: magento

i am new in magento. i want to develop module my custom front side login and registration.and how to manage login user session data? after login user to redirect the account section..Please help me.

Comment: You haven't given much information, what version of Magento? what do you wish to change compared to the original login/registration. Usually we simply extend the existing functionality. Never needed to rewrite it entirely.

Comment: hii... @oliverdeCramer Thank u for reply,  my magento version is 1.9.3, as you reply "Usually we simply extend the existing functionality. Never needed to rewrite it entirel" .so i am try to this...